# How to Keep MapOverlays when screen is rotated

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I have custom Overlays added to a map, but when I change the orientation of the screen the Overlays are removed. Does anybody have any idea how to remedy this??

Before:
[image: Image with overlays]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You change portrait to landscape. It loaded again

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Add the above code in `manifest.xml`.